# Select All Empty Databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm doing some database clean up and I'm looking for a t-sql query that will show me all of the databases that don't have any tables or views.

From this question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114958/list-all-tables-from-all-user-databases/230411#230411

I have a query that will return the tables that have 0 records, but it misses those databases that don't have any tables.

```
If Exists (Select * From tempdb.dbo.sysobjects o Where o.xtype in ('U') And o.id = object_id (N'tempdb..#temptable')) Begin Drop Table #temptable End


DECLARE @src NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = N'', @src = N' UNION ALL 
SELECT ''$d'' as ''database'', 
    s.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI as ''schema'',
    t.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI as ''table'' ,
    ind.rows as record_count
  FROM [$d].sys.schemas AS s
  INNER JOIN [$d].sys.tables AS t ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
  INNER JOIN [$d].sys.sysindexes AS ind ON t.[object_id] = ind.[id]
  --where ind.indid < 2';

SELECT @sql = @sql + REPLACE(@src, '$d', name)
  FROM sys.databases
  WHERE database_id > 4
    AND [state] = 0
    AND HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1;

SET @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, 10, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10));


create table #temptable  (
database_name varchar(max) null,
schema_name varchar(max) null,
table_name varchar(max) null,
record_count int null
)

insert into #temptable
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;

select * from #temptable where record_count = 0 order by 1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE:  This should work (the script ran fine for me) but I dont have any DB's with no tables in my systems, so it is untested in that regard.

I updated the script to do LEFT JOIN on system tables for indexes and tables.  The INNER JOIN required records to exist in those and if you are looking for DBs with no tables, the INNER JOIN would never return those.

I updated your final select as well and put notes on how to get your results if you want to keep tables with 0 recoreds as well as DBs with no tables or not.

```
If Exists (Select * From tempdb.dbo.sysobjects o Where o.xtype in ('U') And o.id = object_id (N'tempdb..#temptable')) Begin Drop Table #temptable End


DECLARE @src NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = N'', @src = N' UNION ALL 
SELECT ''$d'' as ''database'', 
    s.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI as ''schema'',
    t.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI as ''table'' ,
    ind.rows as record_count
  FROM [$d].sys.schemas AS s
  LEFT JOIN [$d].sys.tables AS t ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
  LEFT JOIN [$d].sys.sysindexes AS ind ON t.[object_id] = ind.[id]
  --where ind.indid < 2';

SELECT @sql = @sql + REPLACE(@src, '$d', name)
  FROM sys.databases
  WHERE database_id > 4
    AND [state] = 0
    AND HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1;

SET @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, 10, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10));


create table #temptable  (
database_name varchar(max) null,
schema_name varchar(max) null,
table_name varchar(max) null,
record_count int null
)

insert into #temptable
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;

select * 
FROM #temptable 
WHERE record_count = 0 -- this returns 0 counts in tables (remove if you dont want dbs with tables)
OR table_name IS NULL  -- this should return recors with DBS but no table names
ORDER by 1,2,3,4
```

Comment: I had something similar, but filtered out system schemas and empty tables in the insert.
`LEFT JOIN [$d].sys.sysindexes AS ind ON t.[object_id] = ind.[id] AND ind.rows = 0
  WHERE s.name NOT IN (''guest'',''INFORMATION_SCHEMA'',''sys'',''db_accessadmin'',''db_backupoperator'',''db_datareader'',''db_datawriter'',''db_ddladmin'',''db_denydatareader'',''db_denydatawriter'',''db_owner'',''db_securityadmin'')';`

Answer (score 0):

To get a count of tables in a database you can issue this:

```
declare @howmany int;

select @howmany=count(*) from sys.objects where type='U'
Select 'There are '+cast(@howmany as varchar(10)) +' tables in the database.';
```

Answer (score 0):

@Brad - Thank you for the help and suggestions.
I took your suggestions and expanded upon that.  I added the table type to the union all script then I added a sub-select in the where clause of the temp table and it is giving me what I want.

```
If Exists (Select * From tempdb.dbo.sysobjects o Where o.xtype in ('U') And o.id = object_id (N'tempdb..#temptable')) Begin Drop Table #temptable End


DECLARE @src NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = N'', @src = N' UNION ALL 
SELECT ''$d'' as ''database'', 
    s.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI as ''schema'',
    t.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI as ''table'' ,
    t.type,
    ind.rows as record_count
    FROM [$d].sys.schemas AS s
    LEFT JOIN [$d].sys.tables AS t ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
    LEFT JOIN [$d].sys.sysindexes AS ind ON t.[object_id] = ind.[id]
 '

SELECT @sql = @sql + REPLACE(@src, '$d', name)
  FROM sys.databases
  WHERE database_id > 4
    AND [state] = 0
    AND HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1;

SET @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, 10, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10));


create table #temptable  (
database_name varchar(max) null,
schema_name varchar(max) null,
table_name varchar(max) null,
table_type varchar(max) null,
record_count int null
)

insert into #temptable
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;


select * 
FROM #temptable 
WHERE 
database_name not in (Select database_name from #temptable where table_type = 'u')
ORDER by 1,2,3,4
```